# how can i convert a class which uses template to a normal class which uses Double

Tags: c++, class, templates, math, typename

I thought I was doing good using class templates. But as soon as I started going backwards I had some difficulties. My task is to remove the tempalte realtype class and replace it with a normal double.
I really have no idea how to get started.
My idea was to simply remove this line
and I thought everything will work fine, but I get errors.

ArcBasis.hpp:

```
template <typename RealType>  //line to replace
class K_Arc_Basis
{
    public:
         DECLARE_K_STANDARD (Arc_Basis)

    private:
         typedef K_Arc_Basis<Double> ThisType;
         typedef K_Circle_Basis <Double> CircleType;
    public:
         K_Arc_Basis();
         K_Arc_Basis( const CircleType& Circle );
    private:
         PointType  m_Center;
         Double     m_Radius;
         Double     m_StartAngle;   
         Double     m_Arc;          
    };
```

ArcBasis.inl

```
template <typename RealType>//line to replace
inline K_Arc_Basis<RealType>::K_Arc_Basis()
: m_Center(), m_Radius (1), 
  m_StartAngle( 0 ), m_Arc( 2*KSRealPi( Double(0) ) )
 {
 }

template <typename RealType>//line to replace
inline K_Arc_Basis<RealType>::K_Arc_Basis( const CircleType& Circle )
: m_Center( Circle.Center() ), m_Radius( Circle.Radius() ), 
     m_StartAngle( 0 ), m_Arc( 2*KSRealPi( Double(0) ) )
  {
  }
```

Comment: Type `double` is lowercase

Comment: hahha thank you for your notice but i like defining double like that: typedef double Double;

Comment: Had you already started doing replacement with `typedef K_Arc_Basis<Double> ThisType; typedef K_Circle_Basis <Double> CircleType;`?

Comment: yes i started but i wasn't able to continue replacing all templates

Comment: @ZacBoussaid If you have an alias for a built-in type, a minimal complete example needs to include that alias.

Comment: OK, then just remove `template <typename RealType>` everywhere, and simply use your `Double` where you had `RealType` previously. Then of course it will be just `K_Arc_Basis` instead of templated `K_Arc_Basis<Double>`

Comment: @Caleth you like this ?? using ThisType = K_Arc_Basis<Double>;

Comment: No, I mean there is no mention of `RealType` in your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used the template type anywhere, but you have used a specialisation of that template (and also `K_Circle_Basis`?). You need to remove all the `<Double>` too.

```
class K_Arc_Basis
{
public:
     DECLARE_K_STANDARD (Arc_Basis) // what does this expand to??

private:
     typedef K_Arc_Basis ThisType;
     typedef K_Circle_Basis CircleType;
public:
     K_Arc_Basis();
     K_Arc_Basis( const CircleType& Circle );
private:
     PointType  m_Center; // What is PointType?
     double     m_Radius;
     double     m_StartAngle;   
     double     m_Arc;          
};
```

Alternately, you could start using the type parameter in your template, and provide some explicit instantiations

```
template <typename RealType>
class K_Arc_Basis
{
public:
     DECLARE_K_STANDARD (Arc_Basis)

private:
     using ThisType = K_Arc_Basis<RealType>;
     using CircleType = K_Circle_Basis<RealType>;
public:
     K_Arc_Basis();
     K_Arc_Basis( const CircleType& Circle );
private:
     PointType  m_Center;
     RealType   m_Radius;
     RealType   m_StartAngle;   
     RealType   m_Arc;          
};

using K_Arc_Basis_F = K_Arc_Basis<float>; // or whatever name
using K_Arc_Basis_D = K_Arc_Basis<double>; // or whatever name
```